# Get nth array in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, element

I have a given path with keys (in a separate array) to a subarray within a multidimensional one.

```
$path_array = array( 'first', 'new', 'best');
```

```
$multi_data = array(
  'first' => array(
    'example' => 'good',
    'other' => 'well',
    'new' => array(
      'subset' => 'none',
      'best' => 'stackoverflow',
    )
   )
);
```

The arrays are changing of course due to dynamically generated data.

My Question: How to get the correct value or array by the path that i have got?
A correct static approach would be:

```
echo $multi_data['first']['new']['best'];
// prints: stackoverflow
```

I tried foreach-Loop on $path_array, but i cant put the path elements together (keys is square brackets).

Comment: Will there be duplicates on any key? if so then what's the case there. Also are you just look to return the particular path array from `$multi_data`? Is `$path_array` constant or will be changing as well? And is the order in `$path_array` the order you need to search?

Comment: The values in `$path_array` stand for every indentation level. On each indentation every key is unique. But duplicates on different indentations can occur. `$path_array` will change, too because its generated dynamically.

Comment: So the size of `$path_array` is also `n` and not fixed right? Just a thought, having a path in an array might not be the most efficient way, you should use a linked list.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: don't know why I went through all this trouble with shifting values, foreach works just fine

Could do something like:

```php
$result = $multi_data;
foreach($path_array as $key){
    $result = $result[$key];
}
echo $result;
```

The idea is to get deeper into the array with each iteration. Be extra careful if you might have some non-existent keys, though.

Comment: Just realized i used this way to read the element. How about writing directly to it:
`$a['first']['new']['best'] = 'stackexchange';`

Comment: @Arthur Please remove your advice from this page and transfer it to the the canonical (or at least an earlier asked question)

Comment: @stephan the canonical demonstrate reading and writing using key paths.